# How to install python3.8 on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: python, 23.04

It's strange, but I can't install python3.8 alongside python3.11 on Ubuntu 23.04, and I can't find anything about it either. When I try to install python3.8 like this:

```
sudo apt install python3.8
```

I get an error that this repository does not exist. Also ppa deadsnakes cannot be used:

> compilations are currently supported for:

> jammy

https://github.com/deadsnakes/python3.8

So I have no idea how to deal with this. I would also be happy with replacing 3.11 with 3.8.

Comment: "*I would also be happy with replacing 3.11 with 3.8*" Bad idea. That would destroy your Ubuntu system.

Comment: Never uninstall, replace, or conflict with the version of python3 included with your install of Ubuntu. Ubuntu depends upon that exact version to function. To install a different version of python a virtual environment (venv) is recommended. If you *really* want to install alongside instead of a venv for global use by all users, use a non-packaged version installed to /usr/local.

Comment: you can install all python versions from source in /opt/ if you want to.

Comment: @user535733 "To install a different version of python a virtual environment (venv) is recommended" I'm not sure I get this one. To create venv with other Python version I already need this version installed globally, right?

Comment: @Rinzwind can you guys reccomend any article about installing python from source? I really don't want to mess something up.

Answer (score 1):

## To install Python 3.8 on Ubuntu version 23

Open your terminal and run these commands:

### Install build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
                        libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
                        libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev \
                        libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl git
```

### Download and extract Python 3.8 source code

```
mkdir ~/python38
cd ~/python38
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.16/Python-3.8.16.tgz
tar -xf Python-3.8.16.tgz

cd Python-3.8.16
```

### Configure the build

`./configure --enable-optimizations`

### Compile the source code

`make -j$(nproc)`

### Install Python

`sudo make install`

### Verify the installation

`python3.8 --version`

### To create a virtual environment specify the Python version.

Example:
`python3.8 venv -m venv`